# Setting defaultScope of calendar to Week

Tags: calendar

I am trying to look out for a way to make the defaultScope of calendar view to "Week".  We can do it using the SharePoint UI.

Any idea if I have any property of SPView or SPCalendarView that can be used to make the Weekly View as default scope for List view.

Problem:
- I have a calendar that displays events from multiple calendar (using calendar overlays).
- My home page contains a list view web part of the calendar list.

By default the list view displays monthly view of the calendar.  I would like it to display the Weekly view of the overlayed calendar.

I was thinking if I can make the defaultScope as weekly for the default view of the calendar list, Till now i am not able to find any answer.

Help Help Help... :)

Regards,
Sudhir

Comment: Finally I got the answer. It was not that complicated as I expected.

The calendar rendering is dependent on only one query string parameter "CalendarPeriod".

So if i just append "?CalendarPeriod=week" in to my url the calendar rendering will update itself to display the weekly calendar.

It was so stupid :)

Thanks ashish for directing me to Calendar View Default Scope... moved my answer as commend as per request from Brian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got the answer.  It was not that complicated as I expected.

The calendar rendering is dependent on only one query string parameter "CalendarPeriod".

So if i just append "?CalendarPeriod=week" in to my url  the calendar rendering will update itself to display the weekly calendar.

It was so stupid :)

Thanks ashish for directing me to [Calendar View Default Scope](http://graycloud.com/sharepoint/how-change-calendar-view-default-scope-t48936.html)

Comment: thank you very much for posting the resolution. Can you move it to a comment on your original question so people see it when they first view the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the CalendarPlus webpart, click *Modify Web Part Settings*.
On the *General Settings* tab, change *Default view Period* from Month to **Week**.  Note:  Day is also an option.

If you wish to simply change the calendar itself to view the week, then go to the calendar.  From the ribbon, select *Calendar Tools --> Calendar*.  Select *List Settings.  Scroll down to Views.  Click on the view you wish to edit.  Change *Default Scope* to **Week**.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer,  I was able to figure out the right answer to this,  I have posted the same in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way to change the default scope of calendar view other than UI is to send RPC call to owssvr.dll. For complete solution, visit this link -

http://www.manvir.net/change-the-default-scope-of-sharepoint-calendar-view-to-week/

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Also we  require disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to "Calendar Tools"/"Modify View" and set the default scope to Week!

there is no need to program or use external software.

regards,
Jörg